# Rails Asset Pipeline/Compass/SASS extremely slow to compile in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

Using Rails 3.2, I have approximately 40 SASS files loading in my app.  A large chunk of it is bootstrap.

Each reload of any page takes 10+ seconds.  If I remove `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>` pages load almost instantly.

What's the best way to debug which stylesheets are causing the slowness? Or is it just the fact that I have 40+ partial `.css.scss` files which are all compiled on page refresh?

I have an @import "mixins" at the top of almost every `.scss` file, which loads some base color variables.  Not sure if this might be slowing things down as well, nor do I know how to get these base colors to be available in all `.scss` files any other way...

I'd like to get this slowness fixed before using a live-reload gem, like mentioned here: http://blog.55minutes.com/2013/01/lightning-fast-sass-reloading-in-rails-32/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is an issue as pointed out by fredwu on the rails github:

> I believe it's an issue with Sprockets' resolver:
>   https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/v2.2.2/lib/sprockets/trail.rb#L70-L83
>
> Rails .12 resolves the asset paths manually whereas .13 tries to use
>   Sprockets resolver, which then throws an exception.

The interim issue is to use the following line in your gemfile:

`gem 'rails', git: "git://github.com/rails/rails.git", branch: "3-2-stable"`

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9803

Answer (score 1):

This gem will help:

```
gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '~> 0.6.1'
```

[SOURCE](https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks)

Comment: I have tried this gem, with no success.  There is no noticeable difference in load times.