# Profiling slow assets in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

Every time I make a change to my SASS in development, I get 20s+ load times when loading my `application.css`.

I've read some other questions, and tried:

- Setting `config.assets.debug = false`.
- Changing up imports and requires (I use SASS variables)
- Using Miniprof and its firegraph
- Using [rails-asset_profile](https://github.com/nadarei/rails-asset_profile)

Here's what I read:

- [Rails Asset Pipeline/Compass/SASS extremely slow to compile in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290879/rails-asset-pipeline-compass-sass-extremely-slow-to-compile-in-development-mode?rq=1)
- [Slow assets compilation in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285069/slow-assets-compilation-in-development-mode?rq=1)
- [rake assets:precompile taking extremely long to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739654/rake-assetsprecompile-taking-extremely-long-to-complete)

I've been having this issue from Rails 3.2 and now in 4.2.

I'm going crazy here. How do I find the bottleneck in this mess?

I am looking for a solution that allows me to pinpoint with precision where the time is spent and suggests ways to cut down on that compilation time.

Comment: did you have a look at the browser? which asset is the slow one?

Comment: @phoet Oh, the compiled CSS file. Forgot about mentioning that.

Comment: a simple way to that is using `.css.erb` files and puts statments. just to get any reference points

Comment: How are your files organised? If you use a lot if SASS `@import` statements, you will seriously slow things down if you have a lot of CSS code, since on every change SASS will have to recompile *everything*, and not just a single file. I happened to encounter this scenario earlier this week, and using `require` instead of `@import` solved this; I created a separate `variables.css.sass` file to store variables & mixins (which is `@import`ed in every SASS  file).

Comment: Not an answer, but there is now a [sassc-rails](https://github.com/sass/sassc-rails) working, that might remove the need for profiling!

Comment: Check out: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/tale-front-end-sanity-beware-sass-import

Comment: Have you tried sassc-rails? It speeds up precompiling by x3. It's not gonna work if you are using compass though

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem called [quiet_assets](https://rubygems.org/gems/quiet_assets) that suppresses logging of assets load. In times of rails 3.x it drastically accelerated my development mode. Let me know if this does help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `sprockets` source at [*find* method](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/v3.3.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb#L129) in Sprockets::Manifest class. You can change it to following:

```
paths.each do |path|
  start = Time.now
  puts "Start #{path}"
  environment.find_all_linked_assets(path) do |asset|
    yield asset
  end
  puts "Finished: #{Time.now - start}"
end
```

So it will print all time required to compile each asset. Hope it'll help :)

Edit: This chunk of code is from `master` branch. You can view and edit your current version of `sprockets` by using

```
bundle open sprockets
```

Output after changes:

```
$ rake assets:precompile 
Start admin.css
I, Ä2015-11-28T10:45:26.986231 #45492Ü  INFO -- : Writing /Users/sky/projects/photo_school/public/assets/admin-0e445dcfdc3bd3029943b7d3621b4156c9838eed229c3628f8c558cbb3ce1a59.css
Finished: 10.165564
```

EDIT: changed code a bit and changed link (yesterday put link to a wrong fork: was in a hurry, found out your question only in 15 minutes before bounty closing :)). I checked this code in my project and it works properly (the project uses version 3.3.3 of sprockets).

Comment: Oh, missed that, sorry. Give a try to this block: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb#L120